# Is it necessary to install eslint in order to use eslint-webpack-plugin?

Tags: webpack, eslint

The [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-webpack-plugin) said:

> Note: You also need to install eslint >= 7 from npm, if you haven't already:

But I didn't install eslint and the eslint-webpack-plugin can still work well. Is the eslint  built in the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need ESlint install separately since eslint-webpack-plugin adds `eslint` as a `devDependency`.

However, if you install using `--production` flag, then it is necessary since `devDependencies` will not be installed (But we seldom do that when we want to use Webpack).

Finally, it is a good practice to install `eslint` yourself as it helps you use latest version even if plugin is using older version. Also, some editors do depend on the presence of `eslint` in your application's `package.json` dependencies.